# Single instruction for clearing the Z flag on ARM64?

Tags: arm64

Is there some canonical, or in some sense "best", single instruction for clearing the Z condition code with a single A64 (AARCH64/ARM64) instruction?

I do not care about the other condition codes, so I currently use `MSR NZCV, XZR`, which clears all the N,Z,C,V flags.

A lot of the other "obvious" instructions, like `CMP XZR, #1` seems to be disallowed.

PS. Chat GPT-4 does not know the answer to this.

Comment: Aaaa.... why to clean flag ? Like really, commonly instruction that updates flags is called and result is tested.

Comment: The value of the Z flag is used as the "return value" from an assembler routine.

Comment: That means that some instruction in routine either set or clean this flag. So what's the point in explicit cleaning?

Comment: The tricky thing here is ARM64's encoding convention that "register 31" is XZR in some instruction and SP in others, chosen according to which they thought would be more useful for that particular instruction.  Unfortunately it seems like the usual flag-setting instructions made the choice that doesn't work for us.

Comment: I think we could abuse `ccmp` and do `ccmp xzr, #1, eq, #0`.  Or, something like `cmp sp, #47` which could only be true if your program was seriously misbehaving.

Comment: I'm not sure this is something that comes up often enough to have a "canonical" solution.  Your `msr` approach is certainly the clearest, but it might not be as performant, since generally you'd expect `msr` to be microcoded and slow.  `msr nczv, xN` may or may not be a specially optimized case.

Comment: If you have the flag manipulation instructions (`FEAT_FlagM`, standard from ARMv8.4-A onward) then you can also `rmif xzr, #0, #0x4` which as a bonus doesn't touch the other flags (not that you care in this case).

Comment: Why exactly `cmp xzr, #1` (or `wzr, #1`) is disallowed? (to me it looks like the obvious choice)

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: There's no encoding for such an instruction.  Try it, your assembler will reject it.  `cmp` is an alias for `subs` with the zero register as destination.  In the immediate form of `subs`, the source register can be X0-X30 or SP but not XZR.  There is a 5-bit field in the instruction to specify each register operand.  ARM's definition is that 11111 specifies the zero register in most cases, but the stack pointer in certain others.  This is one of the latter.